# Bootstrap form validation for numbers only

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am new to PHP and want to create a simple form as below and want to validate it and submit it only after proper validation.

I am facing issue with phone validation, Phone validates even when i enter characters, i want to validate numbers and + sign for example +1 12345678, +91 1234123123

how can i validate it for phone numbers only..

> ```
>         <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
>           <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
>           <div class="valid-feedback">Username field is valid!</div>
>           <div class="invalid-feedback">Username field cannot be blank!</div>
>         </div>
>
>         <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
>           <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail Address" required>
>           <div class="valid-feedback">Email field is valid!</div>
>           <div class="invalid-feedback">Email field cannot be blank!</div>
>         </div>
>
>         <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
>           <input class="form-control" type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Phone" required>
>           <div class="valid-feedback">Phone field is valid!</div>
>           <div class="invalid-feedback">Phone field cannot be blank!</div>
>         </div>
>
>         <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
>           <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
>         </div>
>
>         <div class="col-md-12 mt-3">
>           <label class="mb-3 mr-1" for="gender">I am interested in : </label>
>
>           <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="gender" id="male" autocomplete="off" required>
>           <label class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" for="male">Call Back</label>
>
>           <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="gender" id="female" autocomplete="off" required>
>           <label class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" for="female">Brochure</label>
>
>           <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="gender" id="secret" autocomplete="off">
>           <label class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" for="secret">Price details</label>
>         </div>
>
>         <div class="form-button mt-3">
>           <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
>         </div>
>       </form>
>     </div>
>   </div>
> </div>   </div> </div>
> ```

```js
(function () {
'use strict'
const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.requires-validation')
Array.from(forms)
  .forEach(function (form) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      if (!form.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
      }

      form.classList.add('was-validated')
    }, false)
  })
})()
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap');

*, body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #152733;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.form-holder {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      text-align: center;
      min-height: 100vh;
}

.form-holder .form-content {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 60px;
}

.form-content .form-items {
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    padding: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 540px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.form-content h3 {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.form-content h3.form-title {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.form-content p {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}


.form-content label, .was-validated .form-check-input:invalid~.form-check-label, .was-validated .form-check-input:valid~.form-check-label{
    color: #fff;
}

.form-content input[type=text], .form-content input[type=password], .form-content input[type=email], .form-content select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 9px 20px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #8D8D8D;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    margin-top: 16px;
}


.btn-primary{
    background-color: #6C757D;
    outline: none;
    border: 0px;
     box-shadow: none;
}

.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active{
    background-color: #495056;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none !important;
     box-shadow: none;
}

.form-content textarea {
    position: static !important;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #8D8D8D;
    outline: none;
    resize: none;
    height: 120px;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}

.form-content textarea:hover, .form-content textarea:focus {
    border: 0;
    background-color: #ebeff8;
    color: #8D8D8D;
}

.mv-up{
    margin-top: -9px !important;
    margin-bottom: 8px !important;
}

.invalid-feedback{
    color: #ff606e;
}

.valid-feedback{
   color: #2acc80;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-body">
     
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-holder">
                <div class="form-content">
                    <div class="form-items">
                        <h3>Register you interest</h3>
                        <p>Fill in the data below, we will get back to you!</p>
                        <form class="requires-validation" action="SubmitFORM.php" method="POST" novalidate>

                            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                               <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
                               <div class="valid-feedback">Username field is valid!</div>
                               <div class="invalid-feedback">Username field cannot be blank!</div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail Address" required>
                                 <div class="valid-feedback">Email field is valid!</div>
                                 <div class="invalid-feedback">Email field cannot be blank!</div>
                            </div>

                           <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                                 <input class="form-control" type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Phone" required>
                                  <div class="valid-feedback">Phone field is valid!</div>
                                 <div class="invalid-feedback">Phone field cannot be blank!</div>
                           </div>

                           <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                              <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                           </div>


                           <div class="col-md-12 mt-3">
                            <label class="mb-3 mr-1" for="gender">I am interested in : </label>

                            <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="gender" id="male" autocomplete="off" required>
                            <label class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" for="male">Call Back</label>

                            <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="gender" id="female" autocomplete="off" required>
                            <label class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" for="female">Brochure</label>

                            <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="gender" id="secret" autocomplete="off" >
                            <label class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" for="secret">Price details</label>
                            </div>             

                            <div class="form-button mt-3">
                                <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </div>
```

trying to change this example

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of "I want" in this question, and not a lot of "I tried."

Comment: @miken32, from your point of view you are correct, Yes i did try but looking at different reference & example which make it look event confusing, I am still trying i can here only after i was trying to these erros for 3-4 hours... I am stuck at validation only now

Comment: Please add what you have tried and the results it got.  Did any letter in any position pass or just some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding two function to it,

1. I added JS function to allow numbers only on in phone field
2. I also added [international telephone numbers](https://intl-tel-input.com/) for phone formatting for UX as i have also use IP detection to automtically select the country code to about bad inputs or typo which mostly happen when entering country code as some used enter phone numbers without country code, some enter +XXX some enter 00XXX as country code..

below is the link to working example on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/KGuide/pen/YzZjgNv)

```js
(function () {
'use strict'
const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.requires-validation')
Array.from(forms)
  .forEach(function (form) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      if (!form.checkValidity()) {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
      }

      form.classList.add('was-validated')
    }, false)
  })
})()

function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

  var input1 = document.querySelector("#phone");
        // here, the index maps to the error code returned from getValidationError - see readme
        var errorMap = ["Invalid number", "Invalid country code", "Too short", "Too long", "Invalid number"];

         var iti1 = window.intlTelInput(input1, {
            utilsScript: "{{asset('js/utils.js')}}",
            initialCountry: "auto",
            preferredCountries: ['AE', 'US', 'UK', 'SA', 'QA', 'OM', 'IN'],
            setNumber: true,
            formatOnDisplay: true,
            nationalMode: true,
            geoIpLookup: function(success, failure) {
                $.get("https://ipinfo.io", function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
                    var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
                    success(countryCode);
                });
            },
        });

        var reset = function() {
            input1.classList.remove("error");
        };

        // on blur: validate
        input1.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
            reset();
            if (input1.value.trim()) {
                if (iti1.isValidNumber()) {
                    $('#phoneError').hide();
                    input1.classList.remove("is-invalid");
                    input1.classList.add("is-valid");
                    document.querySelector("#phoneinvalid").value = iti1.getNumber();
                } else {
                    $('#phoneError').show();
                    input1.classList.remove("is-valid");
                    input1.classList.add("is-invalid");
                }
            }
        });

        // on keyup / change flag: reset
        input1.addEventListener('change', reset);
        input1.addEventListener('keyup', reset);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap');

*, body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.form-holder {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      text-align: center;
      min-height: 100vh;
}

.form-holder .form-content {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 60px;
}

.form-content .form-items {
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    padding: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 540px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.form-content h3 {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.form-content h3.form-title {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.form-content p {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}


.form-content label, .was-validated .form-check-input:invalid~.form-check-label, .was-validated .form-check-input:valid~.form-check-label{
    color: #fff;
}

.form-content input[type=text], .form-content input[type=password], .form-content input[type=email], .form-content select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 9px 20px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #8D8D8D;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    margin-top: 16px;
}


.btn-primary{
    background-color: #6C757D;
    outline: none;
    border: 0px;
     box-shadow: none;
}

.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active{
    background-color: #495056;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none !important;
     box-shadow: none;
}

.form-content textarea {
    position: static !important;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #8D8D8D;
    outline: none;
    resize: none;
    height: 120px;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}

.form-content textarea:hover, .form-content textarea:focus {
    border: 0;
    background-color: #ebeff8;
    color: #8D8D8D;
}

.mv-up{
    margin-top: -9px !important;
    margin-bottom: 8px !important;
}

.invalid-feedback{
    color: #ff606e;
}

.valid-feedback{
   color: #2acc80;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.13/js/utils.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.13/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.13/css/intlTelInput.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-holder">
      <div class="form-content">
        <div class="form-items">
          <h3>Register you interest</h3>
          <p>Fill in the data below, we will get back to you!</p>
          <form class="requires-validation" action="SubmitFORM.php" method="POST" novalidate>

            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
              <div class="valid-feedback">Username field is valid!</div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">Username field cannot be blank!</div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
              <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail Address" required>
              <div class="valid-feedback">Email field is valid!</div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">Email field cannot be blank!</div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
              <input class="form-control" type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" required>
              <div class="valid-feedback">Phone field is valid!</div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">Phone field cannot be blank!</div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
              <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12 mt-3">
              <label class="mb-3 mr-1" for="gender">I am interested in : </label>

              <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="gender" id="male" autocomplete="off" required>
              <label class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" for="male">Call Back</label>

              <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="gender" id="female" autocomplete="off" required>
              <label class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" for="female">Brochure</label>

              <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="gender" id="secret" autocomplete="off">
              <label class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" for="secret">Price details</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-button mt-3">
              <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define `pattern` you want inside the input tag eg.

```
 <input class="form-control" type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Phone" pattern="[+][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}" required>
```

for +123-45-678

Likewise you can try similar patterns as per your requirement. Hopefully this helps